# Give Google Service Account access to all my Google Analytics Accounts

Tags: google-analytics, service-accounts

My work email has access to around 100 analytic accounts. Is there anyway give a google service account to all of the analytics I have access to with out needing to manually add it to every account?

Comment: No time for a full answer with code, but yes; if your work email is already authorized for all these accounts you can access the Google Analytics Management API via Google Apps Script (e.g. in a spreadsheet) to bulk edit accounts. I do this to bulk add filters, I don't see why this wouldn't work with users. Google Spreadsheets run with the permissions of the logged in user, so they can do everything you have rights to.

Comment: Thanks Eike Pierstorff, I'll look into that!

Comment: but be aware that this solution works up to 100 accounts, see the [Account User Links: insert](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/accountUserLinks/insert) method.

Answer (score 0):

Working off of Eike's comment, it seems to be possible from Google Apps Scripts:

```
function listAccounts() {
  var accounts = Analytics.Management.Accounts.list();
  if (accounts.items && accounts.items.length) {
    for (var i = 0; i < accounts.items.length; i++) {
      var account = accounts.items[i];
      var body = 
      {
        permissions:
        {
          local: ['READ_AND_ANALYZE'] //or whatever permissions you need
        },
        userRef:
        {
          email: 'theemailaddressyouneed'
        }
      };
      Analytics.Management.AccountUserLinks.insert(body, account.id);
    }
  } else {
    Logger.log('No accounts found.');
  }
}
```

You will have to add the "Advanced Google Service" resource: Google Analytics API.

When you run it, you will also need to allow as a user who actually has permissions to add users to GA accounts.

Edit: I forgot to add, this seemed to create a new project for me in the developer console. I got an error message the first time about the project not having the API enabled. Click details or go to the dev console and find this project and enable the Google Analytics API.